# Ubuntu 12.04 install problems - where/how to ask a question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.
I have installed it on two machines, and had to give up on third.
(I was able to simply install 11.10 on the third)

I need to get some help, and I want to give enough context that what I'm
saying makes sense.

Where can I ask for help, and give context?

I also have some questions about updates to the LTS release, and how they get
folded into the distributions I find on the web (eg does 12.04 turn to 12.05)

Where can I ask questions about how the Ubuntu release system works?

I really don't want to labeled as a winner.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases

Answer (score 2):

The best resource I've found for information on release schedules and such is [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Questions about Ubuntu or Ubuntu installation are fine an AskUbuntu main.

Questions about AskUbuntu are for AskUbuntu meta.

Releases you find on the web are going to be off topic per the FAQ.  Only official Ubuntu releases are supported (there is no 12.05).  The numbering system has been explained before, but basically it's:
12.04, 12.04.1, 12.04.2, etc, etc, until it reaches EOL.

Comment: You may want to add that the more prominent version numbers (12.04, 12.10) correspond to a year and an expected months(following a 6-month release cycle in April and October). ALso, why is this being answered in Meta?

Comment: I appreciate the help. I am new to this site, and I'm trying to find my way around.